# Accessing different elements of multidimensional array in parallel using python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing

I have a 3 dimensional array in python. I would like to access different portions of this array in parallel (not all elements). I tried to use the parallel for loop available in joblib. But I am a newbie to multiprocessing and not very clear as to how to use it to access different elements of the same array and get the same array as output. Here's a sample problem. Given a matrix a

```
a=[[2,3],[4,5]]
```

I'd like to parallely replace it's 1st element in 1st row and 2nd element in 2nd row with a modified value (say, adding 1 to 1st and 2 to 2nd).
Thus, expected output would be

```
a=[[3,3],[4,7]]
```

The actual dimensions and task are very large and parallel implementation would really speed up the process. Can anyone suggest a method for this?

Comment: Before considering multiprocessing on shared data (which is considerably hard to implement, especially in python), you should ponder if you really need to optimize the **processing**. Where are you getting your matrices from? Where are you outputting to? If it's from a disk or a network, there's a very good chance that parallelizing *processing* won't bring any measurable performance improvements (you should focus on parallelizing I/O first - or, more likely, partitioning your problem)

Comment: I have images (frames from video) as the input matrices. And I'm attempting to process different connected components (submatrices) in parallel. Each submatrix is filled with the mean value of its bordering elements.

Comment: is this offline or online video processing (as in, do you read from a camera, or a video file)? If it's a camera, how much latency can you tolerate between input and output?

Comment: It is online video processing. I'm trying to reduce the time taken to process a single frame. Currently, the processing is taking about 1.3 seconds. The requirement is to get it to around 2 frames per second. (0.5 seconds per frame).

Comment: that is a *lot* of time. Are you, by chance, representing the images as python lists, as in your example, and doing the processing in pure python? Can you show a bit of your processing code?